# If $A$ is open then $ A= \mathrm{Int}(A)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> If $A$ is open then $ A= \mathrm{Int}(A).$

So we are asked to prove this statement.

I am aware of the other proofs involving neighbourhood but I want to make sure the proof I came up with (given below) is valid.

**Proof:**

By definition of $\operatorname{Int}(A)$, 
\begin{equation}
A^\circ \subseteq A  \tag{1} 
\end{equation}
If we prove $A \subseteq A^\circ$, we are through

Consider an arbitrary $x$ such that
$$x \in A$$
As $A$ is an open set, by definition of open set, we can construct an open ball for some $r_p>0$ $$B(x,r_p)\subseteq A$$

As open balls are also opens sets, $$x \in B(x,r_p) \subseteq \text{ Union of all open subsets  of } A$$

By definition, Union of all open subsets of $A$ = $A^0$  $$\implies x\in A^0$$
\begin{equation}
\implies A \subseteq A^0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that, $A =A^0$

Is this proof valid?

Comment: That works, although if $A^{\circ}$ is the union of all open subsets of $A$, then $A$ itself is a subset of $A$ and thus $A\subseteq A^{\circ}.$

Comment: Your proof works for metric spaces where the concept of an ball with radius makes sense.  In a general topological space,  you need to do without that...

Comment: It is handsome (and legitimate) to think of $A^{\circ}$ as the *largest* open subset of $A$. That reveals immediately that $A^{\circ}=A$ if $A$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

In a general topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, the interior of $A\subseteq X$ is defined as

$$\operatorname{Int}(A) = \bigcup \{O : O \subseteq A \land O \in \mathcal{T}\}$$ i.e the union of all open subsets of $A$ (which is always an open set by the axioms of topology, and a subset of $A$, as all $O$ in the union are).

This is regardless of the way open sets are defined (so your use of open balls is not relevant, metrics don’t come into it).

So if $\operatorname{Int}(A)=A$, the set $A$ is open because it equals the open (by construction) set $\operatorname{Int}(A)$.

And if $A$ is open we can take $O=A$ as one of the sets in the defining union of the interior and so clearly $A$ then equals that union as the largest set among them.

Answer (score 0):

I would change $r_p$ to $r_x$ and as a result  $$B(x,r_p)\subseteq A$$ to $$B(x,r_x)\subseteq A$$ because the radius of the open ball around $x$  depends on the point $x$ and you have not defined $p$

The rest of your proof sounds reasonable.

Comment: You don't need to define $p$ to define $r_p$; $r_x$ just looks better.

Comment: You are correct that there is no need for $r_p$ but since  the center of the open ball is the point $x$ not $p$ it is better to index the radius accordingly.